# Subtitler that showing audio waveform

Tags: video, closed-captions

I'm looking for a subtitler (like [Media Subtitler](https://www.divxland.org/en/media-subtitler) or [Subtitle Workshop](http://subworkshop.sourceforge.net/)) but one that will shows the **audio waveform**.

The audio waveform should be able to help me align the start/end positions of a specific line of subtitle visually and basically achieve a better precision in syncing the subtitles with the audio.

- Windows/Linux/Web
- Trial/share/freeware/OSS

Answer (score 2):

Found just what I was looking for:

https://www.visualsubsync.org/home

> VisualSubSync is a subtitle program using audio waveform representation as it's cornerstone.
>   SRT and SSA/ASS subtitle formats are supported.
>   It also provides some tools (error checking, speed indicators, network suggestions) to help improving the quality of your subtitle.

[image]

It works on Windows (possibly on Linux too through wine).

It seems to be a freeware, not sure if FOSS.